# How to generate Access Token with Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the JavaScript SDK to create an app that lists the users attending a public event. Everything works great when the user is logged in, but I get errors when trying to view the data without being logged in (because there is no access token).

How can I securely generate an access token for the purpose of displaying Event Details without being logged in? I know it can be done server-side with PHP SDK, but I'd rather stick to JavaScript for my purposes unless I have no other choice. Thanks for any replies!

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : '{my-app-id}',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : false
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire

        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        setupApp();
        alert('Connected');

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app

        alert('Not authenticated.');

    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.

        alert('Not logged in.');

    }
}); // end getLoginStatus


function FBLogin() {
    //console.log('login');
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('wooooohoo');
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'rsvp_event,publish_stream,offline_access,friends_events'
    });
}}; // end Init
```

Comment: Even with PHP, OAuth standards require the user to login, see [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/). Your best bet would probably be generating a long-lived token ([seen here under Expiration and Extending Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)) that way you only have to login once and it should cover you for about 60 days before needing to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look into that and see if I can make it work. I only wish there was a way to generate an access token in JS without broadcasting my App Secret to the world...

Comment: Making calls for a User access token will only require the AppID in JS, if anything requires an App Secret (I believe App tokens), Facebook requires that you make the calls server-side for that very reason. If an App token is what you are trying to retrieve, I'm not sure that you can avoid a server-side option. PS - hooray for more girls that code! ;)

Comment: Sadly, I think I will have to resort to server-side. I have nothing against this, or PHP, I was just hoping to be able to keep it all client-side and using JavaScript alone. Thanks again Goose. :)

And yes! Woo-hoo. Girls FTW.